# Transparent background WebEngine javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to lose the white background on the webviewer
i have tried work around and other things but nothing seems to work

```
    public static String url = "URL"; //lets say this has a transparent image on it (it does in my case)
public static Scene FrameWorks;
public static StackPane InnerFrame;
public static WebView viewer;
public static WebEngine webEngine;

public static void web() {
    viewer = new WebView();
    webEngine = viewer.getEngine();
    webEngine.executeScript("document.width");
    WebSite(url);
}

public static void WebSite(String URL) {
    webEngine.executeScript("window.location = \""+URL+"\";");
}

public void start(Stage Level) {
    web();
    InnerFrame = new StackPane();
    FrameWorks = new Scene(InnerFrame, 909, 609);
    InnerFrame.getChildren().add(viewer);
    FrameWorks.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    InnerFrame.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);");
    Level.setScene(FrameWorks);
    Level.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
    Level.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I fully understand your problem so correct me if I am wrong. Do you want everything other than the webview to be transparent? To more or less copy paste a comment from another post, on here I (we) want a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example demonstrating the problem. You should also remember to check if the question has already been asked and answered before asking your own question.

Now that I got that out of the way, here's an example where you can see the stack pane with a black background and the webview with a white background.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;

public class Main extends Application {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        WebView v = new WebView();
        v.setOpacity(1); // 0 = fully transparent, 1 = fully visible.
        v.setPrefWidth(100);
        v.setMaxWidth(100);
        v.setMaxHeight(100);
        v.setPrefHeight(100);
        v.setStyle("-fx-background-color:black;");
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(v);
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-color:black;");

        /*
         * Remove the setStyle above, and use either one of these to only have the webview
         * visible. root.setBackground(Background.EMPTY);
         * root.setStyle("-fx-background-color:TRANSPARENT;");
         */

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

If you remove the line:

```
root.setStyle("-fx-background-color:black;");
```

and replace it with either one of the lines that currently are in comments then you will now only see the webview:

```
/*
 * Remove the setStyle above, and use either one of these to only have the webview
 * visible. 
 * root.setBackground(Background.EMPTY);
 * root.setStyle("-fx-background-color:TRANSPARENT;");
 */
```

And you can of course also set a transparency on the actual webview if you want to do that for some reason:

```
v.setOpacity(0); /*0.0 Fully Transparent - 1.0 Fully Visible*/
```

Please note that to do this I had to set the StageStyle to transparent, and unfortunately I'm not sure if it is possible to do it in any other way. Maybe someone else can put in comments if it is possible or not.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Sadly it did not work [link](https://imgur.com/a/n95oh4i) so the back ground of the php file is transparent but for what ever reason the web viewer has a white background any idea how to change it

Comment: I don't think you can change the background of the actual webview if I am being honest, as it is used to display something that you have no control over such as a web page with its own background color. I thought that you pretty much only wanted to display the webview so I misunderstood the question. Also, from the image alone it's not possible for us to determine if that is actually the webview or perhaps the scene or stackpane background color in white. A minimal but runnable example, together with fxml and css is very helpful in order to give you the best help that we can.